# Getting a matrix ordered

Tags: r

I would like to order and trasform the values of a matrix from the biggest to the smallest value as in this  simple and replicable example :

```
 #From :
 d<- c(-2,-34,25,0,13,0,25,-2,1)
 m<- matrix(d,3,3)
 m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   -2    0   25
[2,]  -34   13   -2
[3,]   25    0    1

# To:
m1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    4    1
[2,]    6    2    5
[3,]    1    4    3

#25: biggest number therefore -->(1)
#13: second biggest one ---> (2)
# ecc ...
#-34: the smallest one ---> (6)
```

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You can convert d to factor and then get rid of the levels. (This means you don't need any extra packages.)

```
m1 <- m
m1[]<-unclass(factor(d, levels = sort(unique(d), decreasing=TRUE)))
# alternative solutions from comments
# or levels=sort(-d), thanks, akrun
# or, to make it shorter: m1[] <- unclass(factor(-d))
# or, [eddi's suggestion using implicit conversions]: m1[] <- factor(-m) 
m1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    5    4    1
# [2,]    6    2    5
# [3,]    1    4    3
```

Comment: doesn't just `m[] <- as.numeric(factor(m * -1))` work? very clever

Comment: akrun had a good answer using `dplyr::dense_rank` which he regrettably deleted. I think R's philosophy is that there are many ways of arriving at (almost) any answer, so base-R and dplyr or whatever solutions should be equally welcome. (My notice on no need for extra packages was not meant to say his solution is bad in any sense.)

Comment: `m1[] <- unclass(factor(-d))` would do it  as well :) `unclass` is preferred over `as.numeric` as per R manuals, because factors are already numeric. `unclass` removes the extra attributes (class and levels) which make factor a factor.

Comment: @lebatsnok  It's okay.  I don't hold any grudge :-)  I gave you plus one and I think a base R solution is only needed for here.

Comment: @akrun but you had a point: extra packages don't cost anything -- except for some learning time, I'd say, which may be the deal breaker in many cases, but it shouldn't be  for `dplyr`

Comment: the only thing unclass removes is the class, hence the name.. otherwise `\`class<-\`(unclass(factor(1, labels = 'a')), 'factor')` wouldn't work

Comment: `m1[] <- factor(-m)` imo; all the conversions will be implicit

Comment: @rawr you're right, unclass doesn't remove the labels attribute.

Comment: @eddi, this is shorter but then again, implicit conversions are dangerous and sometimes hard to predict. eg. `matrix(factor(-m),3,3)` will result in a character matrix, so one would need `unclass` or `c` (the latter would remove all attributes, including levels and labels) --> `m1<-matrix(c(factor(-m),3,3)` would be a one-line solution

Comment: @lebatsnok yeah, they are dangerous, but l̶i̶f̶e̶  code golfing is no fun without some danger

Answer (score 6):

An approach with `base` `rank`:

```
#get unique values, since rank itself doesn't
#  seem to have an option that allows the 
#  ranking system you have in mind
u_m = unique(c(m))

#"merge" with match
matrix(rank(-u_m)[match(m, u_m)], nrow = 3L, ncol = 3L)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    5    4    1
# [2,]    6    2    5
# [3,]    1    4    3
```

While `base::rank` doesn't have a way to get what you want right away, we can use `frank` (as noted by @eddi), an improved and efficient version of `rank` in the `data.table` package, like so:

```
library(data.table)
matrix(frank(-m, ties.method = "dense"), nrow = 3L, ncol = 3L)
```

Or, if the matrix part looks ugly, just pre-allocate something as a matrix, *a la*

```
m1 = m
m1[] = frank(-m, ties.method = "dense")
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dense_rank`

```
library(dplyr)
m1 <- m
m1[] <- dense_rank(-m)
m1
#    [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    5    4    1
#[2,]    6    2    5
#[3,]    1    4    3
```

Comment: No such thing as free lunch! Disc space is something to keep in mind (albeit generally minor), especially given all the dependencies of `dplyr`

Comment: The solution is a compact one, but I understand the bias in voting.  So, in your solution, also you mentioned `data.table`.  Doesn't that have these dependency problem???